# Refreshing Facebook share cache for an entire domain?

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-opengraph

The OG tags on a domain were broken for sometime and FB has cached the bad data for quite a few pages. Everything's corrected now, but FB's cache seems to last quite some time.

I know I can expire and repopulate the cache for a single page by using this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I'd like to get that done to every page on my site. Is there anyway to have FB recrawl all pages that are liked/shared from my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. Just use the debugger for every page on your domain. There is also a `rescrape=true` param for the graph API if you get rate limited by the debugger.